# check if main actor is finished

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

As i am creating actor system and creating main actor i.e. actorModel that creates about 15 other actors. Now, what happens that the true is returned before the completion of actorModel. I want the true to be returned from this method when the actorModel has finished its task or the actor system has finished its task. you know what i mean.! Help...

```
def doWork:Boolean ={
/* some code here....
 *
 */
val system=ActorSystem("system")
val actorModel=system.actorOf(Props(new ActorModel(userId,dateTimeId,form)),"actorModel")

true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to ask the `actorModel` and `Await` the response.

```
val f = actorModel ? AreYouFinished
Await.ready(f, timeout)
```

The `ActorModel` would need to keep track of senders of the `AreYouFinished` message and respond to them when the task is finished.

```
case AreYouFinished =>
  finishedWaiters = sender :: finishedWaiters

case TaskFinished =>
  finishedWaiters foreach (_ ! TaskFinished)
```

This is a use case where `ask` and `Await` are useful: non-actor code waiting on the results of an actor.  You wouldn't normally wait to use `Await` in an actor.

Note that actor systems are fairly heavyweight.  You usually would have one for your whole application, rather than firing one up as needed in a function.  Also per waffle paradox you also need to make sure it is shut down.  But usually you would shut it down when your app shuts down.

Comment: Actually, I am new to akka. Since, i see a timeout is there And it will wait for the timeout But i dont know how much time my task will take. Isnt'd there any way to avoid the timeout and keep waiting until the response of sent msg comes!

Comment: Just set a long timeout then. In reality you need to be prepared for the result to never come back.  If it never came back your program would be hung.

Answer (score 1):

Use `system.awaitTermination()` before return with `true`.

Comment: A note just in case: he will need to call `system.shutdown` when he's finished doing whatever he needs, or else the system will never terminate.